# linkbuttons behaviour postbacks versus not postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can you help me understand why, when the page is first loaded by the example below, the buttons don't work as intended eg Button 2 doesn't call  `GetItems(int.Parse("2"), 3);` but rather calls  `GetItems(int.Parse("4"), 3);` however after the first postback all the buttons work correctly e.g. Buttonx calls `GetItems(int.Parse("x"), 3);` 
Thanks

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if(!IsPostBack)
                {
                    GetItems(1, 2); //default values (first time the page is loaded)

                }
                GenerateButtons(5);
            }

 private void GenerateButtons(int c)
        {
            LinkButton[] x = new LinkButton[c];

            for(int i=0; i<c;i++)
            {
                x[i] = new LinkButton();
                x[i].Text = (i+1).ToString();
                Panel1.Controls.Add(x[i]);

                x[i].OnClick += new EventHandler(Button_Click);

            }
        }
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;  // Which button was clicked;

            GetItems(int.Parse(button.Text), 3); //3 is a constant; first argument is index of button extracted from its caption

        }
```

PS. when I refer to button 1 I have `button[0]` in mind. `button2=button[1]` and so on. after postback `button1` is correctly attached to the event to trigger `GetItems(1,3)`. Before the postback button1 causes `GetItems(3,3)` to run. Not as intended

Comment: use the `Page_Init` so it will work on the first load

Comment: I had post it as answer hope you marked it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Page_Init so it will work on the first load

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GenerateButtons(5);
}
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

> `Init` Raised after all controls have been initialized and any skin
>   settings have been applied. The Init event of individual controls
>   occurs before the Init event of the page. Use this event to read or
>   initialize control properties

.

Answer (score 1):

When you dynamically create controls you do so in `Page_PreInit` not `Page_Load`

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 GenerateButtons(5);
}
```

This article explains and will help you

http://www.robertsindall.co.uk/blog/dynamically-adding-web-controls/

Comment: Thanks prospector. Just tried this, but then the buttons are not available the first time I load the page. I need them to work in both cases.